# Python problems with file names

Tags: python, unicode, directory

I'd like to find a function that accesses a directory using the os.listdir() function (or any other method) and returns all the file names in that directory but converts non-ASCII characters into their unicode format. For example, if I had the file `Hello WorlЪ.py`, I'd like for the function to return `Hello Worl\u042a.py` or something equivalent. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass `os.listdir` a unicode path, then `os.listdir` returns unicode:

```
os.listdir(u'.')
```

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> Changed in version 2.3: On Windows NT/2k/XP and Unix, if path is a
>   Unicode object, the result will be a list of Unicode objects.
>   Undecodable filenames will still be returned as string objects.

Comment: Thank you, @unutbu. This worked with a little bit of tweaking.

Answer (score 4):

`str.encode("unicode_escape")` will encode a string in the way you described.

```
>>> print(u"Hello WorlЪ.py".encode("unicode_escape"))
Hello Worl\u042a.py
```